# Where does electrostatic interaction come from?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, interactions

**Naive view of particle physics**
The interactions come from fermionic particles exchanging bosons. Specifically, electromagnetic interactions result from charged particles exchanging photons.

**Question**
Is the electrostatic interaction simply a limiting case of such photon exchange at very low frequencies? This seems to be logical, since otherwise it would be instantaneous.